# Find attribute with selenium

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, selenium

I'm using selenium and i found this web element :

```
<td style="padding-right: 10px; " **onclick="javascript:show_me('CarDetails.php?CarID=2358912&SubCatID=1**', '2358912', 560, 'ActiveLinkVisited');stat( '../', 176, '', '' );" id="Txt_2358912">blabla</td>
```

I want to grab the `"onclick"` attribute information (the `javascript:show`... text).

How can i do it with selenium (like the `attr` function in `DOM`).

Thanks, 
Or.

Edit : I will clarify my question.
I have something like this :

```
<tr id="tr_2358912" class="ActiveLink" onmouseover="this.className='overActiveLink'" onmouseout="(document.getElementById("TxtID2358912").innerText!="bla") ? this.className="ActiveLink" : this.className="openActiveLink" ">
    <td valign="middle">
    <td width="2"/>    
    <td id="Txt_2358912" onclick="javascript:show_me('CarDetails.php?CarID=2358912&SubCatID=1', '2358912', 560, 'ActiveLinkVisited');stat( '../', 176, '', '' );" style="padding-right: 7px; ">Text Here</td>
    <td width="2"/>
```

And I have a WebElement that contains the ActiveLink class :

`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("ActiveLink"));`

I want from the elements object get the onclick value

```
("javascript:show_me('CarDetails.php?CarID=2358912&SubCatID=1', '2358912', 560, 'ActiveLinkVisited'").
```

I tried with
`element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick]")).getText()` 
And tried alot more.. but with no success.
I'm kind of new with this..
I hope that someone can help me..
Thanks!

Comment: attr function in DOM? There is an attr function in jquery and native javascript is somenode.getAttribute("attrname")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String onclick=selenium.getAttribute("//td[contains(@onclick,'CarDetails.php')]@onclick");

onclick=onclick.substring(onclick.indexOf(":")+1)
```

Comment: Please look at my clarify at the original message.
I tried to type : 

'element.getAttribute("//td[contains(@onclick,'CarDetails.php')]@onclick");'

but i'm getting null object.

Comment: I think it is (//td[contains(@onclick,'CarDetails.php')]) visible after placing the mouse over tr[id='tr_2358912']. So, first place the mouse over the tr and then try to execute above statments

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the attribute selector:

```
selector=//selector/used/to/find/the/td/@onclick
```

Comment: Great, i secceed to grab the attribute, but how do i get the "javascript:show_me('CarDetails.php?CarID=2358912&SubCatID=1" text?

Comment: Use the text() selector like: `selector=//selector/used/to/find/the/td/@onclick/text()`

Comment: I want to access the onclick attribute from my element (please look my clarify for the message. thanks!

Comment: Did you try this: `element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick]/@onclick/text()"))`

Comment: I'm using debugger and when i'm trying to use :

element.findElement(By.xpath("//td")) - find the element
element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick]")) - find the element
element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick]/@onclick")) - I'm getting NoSuchElementException..
and of course also the same exception when i'm trying the all :
element.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@onclick]/@onclick/text()"))
From some reason it is cannot find the @onclick element?